# Debug random SIGSEGV crash

Tags: java, linux, docker, jvm, apache-kafka-connect

We are experiencing random JVM crashes while running a Kafka Connect application in distributed mode. The connect application runs a custom connector with a custom task implementation. The application runs on a Docker container which has an Alpine Linux as the base image. The crashes are completely random and what I mean by that is:

1. The error logs are not pointing to the same stack trace for every crash ( see below )
2. The crashes happen at random points in time on different machines
3. Pushing the underlying VM ( High CPU load, high memory load, high IO disk load ) has no effect whatsoever on the frequency of the crashes

[Machine 1 Crash](https://pastebin.com/R9FXrfUV)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc1e92df777, pid=48, tid=0x00007fc1d899eae8
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.6.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Tue Nov 21 11:22:36 GMT 2017)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x4c4777]  JVM_FindSignal+0x52586
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/kafka/core or core.48
```

[Machine 2 Crash](https://pastebin.com/ndzwaj0a)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7825f1da82, pid=48, tid=0x00007f78179bbae8
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.6.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Tue Nov 21 11:22:36 GMT 2017)
# Problematic frame:
# j  io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/util/Enumeration;)V+115
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/kafka/core or core.48
```

[Machine 3 Crash](https://pastebin.com/63LTmLKR)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe4463fc2bc, pid=48, tid=0x00007fe435e06ae8
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.6.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Tue Nov 21 11:22:36 GMT 2017)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjvm.so+0x27b2bc]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/kafka/core or core.48
```

[Machine 4 Crash](https://pastebin.com/KEBGwMWQ)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f130fcb1b93, pid=48, tid=0x00007f130d65a700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b03) (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-2~deb9u1-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x760b93]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/kafka/core or core.48
```

And the list continues like this.
Some other things to be mentioned:

- no application logs
- no core dump is written ( checked the location mentioned in the error file but there is nothing in there )

Things we tried so far with no effect:

- switch from Alpine based docker image to Debian
- excluding Prometheus Agent
- update Open JDK version from 8.0.151 to 8.0.212

Any tip on finding the issues would be more than appreciated!

Comment: Has the core dump capture enabled on the system?

Comment: Looks like a heap corruption. First, check if the problem is caused by JVM itself. Try 1) different GC, e.g. `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`; 2) disable tiered compilation: `-XX:-TieredCompilation`; 3) leave only C1 compiler: `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`. BTW, to enable core dumps, use `ulimit -c unlimited`

Comment: The core dump is enabled but limited to 500.000. Thanks for the suggestions, currently we are undergoing a test with Open JDK 11 and it seems to be stable for now. I will keep you up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using JRE 11 for running the application has fixed the issue. The project is still built using Java 8 but running it with Java 11 has stopped the crashes.